# Same computer, Same Ubuntu, Brother prints from USB key boot, NOT from SSD boot

Tags: 12.10, printing

this is very strange : I have a Printer (**Brother DCP-J315W**) usb connected to my Desktop. If :

1. I boot on *USB KEY* (**Fresh 12.10 install**, 64bits),
2. Install brother [printing drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J315W),
3. Add new printer (local, usb) and ask to print the test page

**IT PRiNTS** !

But, If :

1. I boot on the *internal SSD* (**Fresh 12.10 install**, 64bits),
2. Install brother [printing drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J315W),
3. Add new printer (local, usb) and ask to print the test page

It hangs on "**Printer Status : Inactive - Sending data to printer.**"

[image]

On both :

```
$dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  dcpj315wcupswrappe 1.1.3-1   i386     Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  dcpj315wlpr 1.1.3-1 i386 Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-ptouch 1.3-4ubuntu1
```

- If **printing over the network** (from Desktop, remote, wireless, SSD boot) SAME error.
- If printing over the network (from a laptop, 12.10, 64bits too) or Android : No problems, it prints just fine.

I can't believe it !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Brother was intended for my Grand mother's desktop.

It seems they don't get on well with eachother ! fine, I simply swaped my **Canon MP495** for her **Brother DCP-J315W**. Took me 5 mn to install the canon on her desktop, and 5 more to install the Brother on mine.

Still don't know the potential causes of the problem, but I can fairly say it's kind of Solved now !

I clearly hit a snag...